# How can I do a select following a select in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Here's the code I have:

```
    var a = Times
            .Where(x => Int32.Parse(x.DateYYMMDD) > Int32.Parse("200309"))
            .GroupBy(x => x.DateYYMMDD)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .Select(g => new ScreenTimeModel
            {
                DateYYMMDD = $"20{g.Key.Substring(0, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(2, 2)}/{g.Key.Substring(4, 2)}"
            })
            .Select(g => new ScreenTimeModel
            {
                DateYYMMDD = (g => g.DateYYMMDD),
            })
```

It's simplified but what I would like to do is some processing of the value of DateYYMMDD that's put into the first .Select.

I tried to get that data with this (g => g.DateYYMMDD) but it's not working.

Can someone tell me how I can get references to the DateYYMMDD in the first select?

Comment: You just need `DateYYMMDD = g.DateYYMMDD`.

Comment: The first `g` is an `IGrouping` while the second `g` is `ScreenTimeModel`

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you **actually** trying to achieve, Maybe this can all be done in one `Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the first [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8) method and update the second a little bit, to get a `ScreenTimeModel` with `DateYYMMDD` assigned to the group key

```cs
 .Select(g => new ScreenTimeModel
        {
            DateYYMMDD = g.DateYYMMDD,
        }
```

in your current code the first `Select` get the `IGrouping<TKey,TElement>` as `g` parameter, in the second `Select` parameter `g` is `ScreenTimeModel`. I don't think that you will need to call it twice